# How to pass component to library (pass ng-template into component)

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-library

I need pass iterated component into another component, something like that:

```
<component-a>
  <ng-template *ngFor="let item of items">
    <component-b [options]="item"></component-b>
  </ng-template>
</component-a>
```

I tried different ways to display component-b but unfortunately don't got result.
One of them use *@ContentChildren* decorator 
`@ContentChildren(TemplateRef, {descendants: true}) template: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>;`

I've got templateRefs array and use forEach to *createEmbeddedView* into *ngAfterContentInit*

```
this.template.forEach(item => {
  this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(item);
});
```

If i doing that in *ngAfterContentInit* i've got next error

```
AppComponent.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'options: undefined'. Current value: 'options: [object Object]'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?
```

but component displaying.
What im missing? Maby i should go another way?

If i move that into *ngAfterContentChecked* ive got infinity loop

Component-a HTML:

```
<div class="component-a">
  <ng-container></ng-container>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Component-b Static text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by this.viewTemplateRef.createEmbeddedView(item).detectChanges();